# Setting up a grid. Eloquent js chapter 7

Tags: javascript

(http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_elife.html)

Im having a hard time understand what the Grid methods we added .get and .set even do.Firstly, lets go through an example  case. 
`var grid = new Grid(5,5)`;
now space is an array of `25` elements. And of course `width` and `height` `are` 5.

Now the question is what is the method of "get" doing.

Now we said `console.log(grid.get(new Vector(1, 1)));.`

So `x` becomes `1`, `y` becomes `1` in the new object we created. Of course we need to do grid.get thus we return `this.space[1+ 1 * 5]` i.e the 6th spot in the space array which is `25` elements long. So why does this print undefined? Is it because there isn't anything in the space array?

**TLDR**

How do the `.get` and `.set`prototypes work here ( what do they do)? Also why do we set   `return this.space[vector.x + this.width*vector.y];`, is there some numerical significance to `vector.x+this.width*vector.y`?

```
    function Vector(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    Vector.prototype.plus = function(other){

        return new Vector(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
    }


    var grid = ["top left",    "top middle",    "top right",
        "bottom left", "bottom middle", "bottom right"];


    function Grid (width,height){

        this.space = new Array(width * height);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

    }

    Grid.prototype.isInside = function(vector){


        return vector.x >=0 && vector.x<this.width && vector.y>=0 && vector.y<this.height;

    }

    Grid.prototype.get = function(vector){

        return this.space[vector.x + this.width*vector.y];
        // 5 + 5 * 1;

    }

    Grid.prototype.set = function(vector,value){

        this.space[vector.x + this.width *vector.y] = value;

    }

    var grid = new Grid(5, 5);

    console.log(grid.get(new Vector(1, 1)));
    // → undefined
    grid.set(new Vector(1, 1), "X");
    console.log(grid.get(new Vector(1, 1)));
    // → X
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if I can be clearer than the article you are already following, but I will give it a try.

This: `new Array(25)` is equivalent to this: `[undefined, undefined, undefined, ...25x]`

In your code, you have this:

`var grid = ["top left", "top middle", "top right", "bottom left", "bottom middle", "bottom right"];`

then declaring the same var again:

`var grid = new Grid(5, 5);`

So, ultimately, `grid` is equal to `[undefined, undefined, undefined, ...]`. That's why you get undefined before setting anything.

---

`get` and `set`, simply find the position of an item in the array, and read, or write the value in said position. This is the code that finds the position in the array: `vector.x+this.width*vector.y`. Let's break it down:

`vector.x` = table column

`vector.y` = table row

Imagine a table 3x2 = [ 'row0 col0', 'row0 col1', 'row0 col2',  'row1 col0', 'row1 col1', 'row1 col2' ]

now we want item at col 2, row 1, so `new Vector(2, 1)`. That's item at position 5 in our array. So, starting at row 1 ( this.width*vector.y ) = (3*1), get item at column 2 ( + vector.x) = ( + 2 )

this.width is the size of each row, so when you multiply by vector.y, it means vector.y is equivalent to a certain number of rows. Then from there, you just sum the column position (vector.x).

---

**Representing tabular data**

A table has several rows, and each row has several columns, so you could represent a table using an array for each row, like:

```
row1 = ['item1', 'item2'];
row2 = ['item3', 'item4'];

table = [row1, row2];
```

That would give you a multidimensional array: `[ ['item1', 'item2'], ['item3', 'item4'] ]`

Meaning you would access the data like: `table[ rowIndex ][ columnIndex ]`

But the method you are using, stores all the items in a single list, a single array: `table = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']`

Now let's say we want to find the same item as in the previous example, using `rowIndex` and `columnIndex`, except this time there is only one single list of items, so we need to combine `rowIndex` and `columnIndex` into a single number, to get the item using: `table[ indexOfItemIWant ]`. How do we do that? You know that all rows are listed one after the other, and all rows have the same number of items on it. So to find the beginning of a row in our list, we multiply the size of the rows, by the amount of rows we want to skip. In a table where each row has two items, like in our example, the first row starts at position 0, and occupies two positions, so the next row, starts at position 0 + 2, then the next, at position 0 +2 +2, then 0 +2 +2 +2 and so on, that's why you use `width` (number of items in a row) times the row I want to get (vector.y).

Comment: Hmm... I think I understand but I might need to think about it more

Comment: So what does vector.x + this.width*vector.y actually represent? Is that where we are going to place something?

Comment: I will add a few more details soon on how the whole vector thing works...

Answer (score 2):

A `space` is an array, and a `vector` is used for transform from 2 dimension (x, y) to an index i into `space`, so that .set will set a value `x` to that index i, and .get is used to get/read whatever value been set by .set.

And for a location inside space, say `space[j]` is undefined if is is not been `set` before.

Comment: So what exactly is the signifance of vector.x + this.width *vector.y?

Comment: Transform Vector(x, y) to an index in space, for example Vector(1, 1) is the second row and second in second, and it translated into index 6 inside space. Trying to image that how would you do it by hand or paper to translate (x, y) position into a 1 dimension array.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the very good explanation by Hugo Silva above. I was struggling to understand the same code, while doing Chapter-7. The general arithmetic behind converting a 2D array into 1D is

2d[i][j] = 1d[ j + i * Total_number_of_columns_in_the_matrix ]

In other words..

2d[height][width] = 1d[ width + height * Total number_of_columns_in_the_Matrix ]

With ‘i’ representing the row number (i.e. height or distance from the top of the Matrix), and ‘j’ the column number (i.e. width or distance from the left of the Matrix). And that, I start numbering from i,j = (0,0) representing a position at row 0 and column 0, for a [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) ordering (i.e. consecutive elements of the rows of the array are contiguous in memory and all the rows are listed one after other).

So, [0][1] is the second item on the top row, [1][n] is on the second row and so forth.

The array elements here in a single row are in groups of 3 ("top left", "top middle", "top right"). So, I need to find the index or count of where the group that I want is starting. That’s what the part of the formula  **i * Total_number_of_columns_in_the_matrix** does. Once I find where the group I want starts, then I add j to get the count of the cell I want.

While counting the index for the first row (which represents i=0), I don't have any previous counts of elements to add. So the Array indices for the first row will just be 0,1,2.

Then, as I get to the second row (i = 1), now, because, I already have 3 entries from the first row, so I need to start with indices 1*3 + 0,1,2 and so on.

A quick [blog post](https://rohan-paul.github.io/javascript/2016/09/09/How_to_Emulate_a_2_Dimensional_array_in_JavaScript_into_a_1_Dimensional-array.html) I wrote on this, just to document my own understanding.